# grouopby.apply function isnt producing correct result

Tags: python, apply

I have a data set that im grouping by account, name, and date. And creating a function to keep only the min value of 'alt_fee' of each unique combination.

```
def drop(df):
   return df[df['alt_fee']==df['alt_fee'].min()]
result = df.groupby(['account', 'name', 'date']).apply(drop)
```

This is giving me more rows than needed. I can see more than one entry for each unique account, name, and date combination. I am unsure why.
In the dataframe that it produces, the columns that are in the index, account, name, and date. there are a few that are identical. But I see that the numerical index is different. Maybe theres a way to drop index before grouping.

I notice that when I put this code into function:

```
def drop(df):
    return df['alt_fee'].min()
```

It gives me the specific rows back that I want. But then I dont know how to get the rest of the dataframe back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this without using `apply()` at all. When using the `groupby` function, only one record for each combination will be returned. By using `min()` as the aggregator, the minimum value for all other numeric fields in your data will be returned.

```py
result = df.groupby(['account', 'name', 'date']).min()
```

##### Addressing comment

You can take just the `alt_fee` column from the above code, and then merge it back with the original dataset.

```py
result = df.groupby(['account', 'name', 'date']).min()[['alt_fee']].reset_index()
result = result.merge(df, on=['account', 'name', 'date', 'alt_fee'])
```

**Note:** if there are multiple rows that have the same `alt_fee`, you would need to drop the duplicates afterwards

```py
result = result.drop_duplicates(['account', 'name', 'date', 'alt_fee'], keep='first')` to remove those values.
```

Comment: How would I use this technique to find the min of specifically the "alt_fee" column.

Comment: The `alt_fee` column would be included in the output, and the value would be the minimum `alt_fee` value for each combination of `['account', 'name', 'date']`

Comment: I also want the entire dataframe, all the columns in the dataframe. just the columns that match with these parameters

Comment: Do you have more columns than the 3 used in the `groupby` and `alt_fee`?

Comment: Yes. Theres 8 columns in total.

Comment: If the updated solution solves this issue, can you accept the answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244485/discussion-between-learnin333-and-desi-pilla).

Answer (score 0):

Just got it. Here is the code in case someone else gets stuck here.

```
def drop(df):
    return df[df['alt_fee'] == df['alt_fee'].min()].drop_duplicates(subset=(['account', 'name','date']),keep='first')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).